# squirrelmail not working after installing mod_jk

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk, squirrelmail

I have installed mod_jk so that I can forward traffic from Apache to tomcat, after that squirrelmail (the only app I have running in apache) stopped working with the followinError connecting to IMAP server: server.formkat.com.
0 : php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not knowng error: 
I have added the following line to httpd.conf in order to keep squirrelmail  traffic from being forwarded to tomcat but still it does not work...
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/squirrelmail*" no-jk
Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I added my name server to the hosts file and it is working now...I do not understand why but it is working.